# Python VLC Script error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'media_player_new'

Tags: python, vlc

I'm trying to make a simple script that will play a video (.mp4) in python. I don't want to play a you tube video or anything online, just a video on my computer.

Here's my code:

```
import vlc
Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new('test.mp4')
Media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
```

I keep getting this error when I run it (talking about line 3):

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'media_player_new'

I'm using python 3.5.4 in the IDLE on macOS Sierra.

Comment: I could imagine that there is a conflict with how you name your objects. As a rule of thumb, never use upper-case letters for objects or variables (only for classes). In line 2 change `Instance` to `vlc_instance` or similar and rename in the other lines as well.

Comment: that didn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by comment out find_lib() in vlc.py.

```
p = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(os.path.join(p, 'sdk'))
dll = ctypes.CDLL("libvlc.dll")
plugin_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), r'sdk\plugins')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not holding the instance open

```
import vlc
Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new('2005.mp3')
Media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
while player.get_state() !=6:
    continue
```

Should work or
try this:

```
import vlc
import time
import sys

def progressbar(progress,guage_length=50):
    div = 100 / float(guage_length)
    prog = int(progress / div) # ensure progress fits in guage
    text = "\rPlaying: {0}{1}{2} [{3}%]".format(">"*prog,"|","-"*(guage_length - prog),format(progress,'.2f'))
    sys.stdout.write(text)
    sys.stdout.flush()

instance = vlc.Instance()
player = instance.media_player_new()
player.set_mrl("V2.mp4")
player.play()
playing = set([1,2,3,4])
play=True
guage_length=30
while play == True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    play_state = player.get_state()
    if play_state in playing:
        length = player.get_length()
        ptime = player.get_time()
        progress = ptime/float(length)*100
        progressbar(progress,guage_length)
        continue
    else:
        progressbar(100,guage_length)
        play = False
print ("\nPlay terminated")
```

Note that # State 0: None,1 Opening,2 Buffering,3 Playing,4 Paused,5 Stopped,6 Ended,7 Error

Caveat: tested on Linux only

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code using simply

```
import vlc
p = vlc.MediaPlayer('2005.mp3')
p.play()
```

but this would not solve your problem. Apparently, the vlc instance is not correctly created. This can be caused by a variety of issues. Use

```
i = vlc.Instance('--verbose 3')
```

to see possible error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message on a Raspberry Pi Zero with Raspbian Buster Lite. I searched a long time for the answer but suddenly I noticed the remark on the [pypi project page of python-vlc](https://pypi.org/project/python-vlc/):

> Note that it relies on an already present install of VLC.

So installing vlc with `sudo apt install vlc` solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The fix of `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'media_player_new'` for onefile for windows is  `--add-data "./plugins/;./plugins/"` make sure that plugins is in the same path as main.py

Make sure to copy plugins folder from the VLC binary path before launching the command also don't forget to add DLLs files too with :

`--add-data "libvlc.dll;." --add-data "libvlccore.dll;." --add-data "axvlc.dll;." --add-data "npvlc.dll;."`